# Selenium not taking in specified elements

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm trying to take all the pill panels on the page: 
   https://pillreports.net/index.php?page=region_home&region=3&sub_region=28

```
if msg.content.startswith(";pill"):
    pill = msg.content[5:]

    browser.get("https://pillreports.net/index.php?page=region_home&region=3&sub_region=28")
    panels = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("row row-search")
    print(panels)

    try:

        for i in range(0,15):
            print(i)
            search = panels[i].find_element_by_class_name("top_pad").text

            if search.lower == pill.lower:
                panels[i].click()
                break

    except NoSuchElementException:

        await bot.send_message(msg.channel, "Pinga not found dard")
        return
```

All the panels have the class name "row row-search" but they are not being saved into the panels variable. There is no error presented when it tries to save them, it just continues. When it hits the loop it says that it is out of index range. When I print the variable panels it has nothing in it.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: class="row row-search" means that element has two classes(row and row-search).Try: panels = find_elements_by_class_name("row-search")

Comment: That has worked! Thank you :)

Comment: @Braca : You might wanna add this to answer , so that Blake can accept it , and this query would be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class="row row-search" means that element has two classes("row" and "row-search").Try:

`panels = find_elements_by_class_name("row-search")`